# Can I identify and set network device names in an Anaconda kickstart file?

Tags: anaconda, rhel

I'm creating a kickstart file for RHEL 8 and am trying to simplify network connectivity among machines. All of the machines will have onboard ethernet ports that will distribute eno1 and eno2 names, but also a separate card which will generate unique names when RHEL is installed.

My question is, can I use the kickstart to identify copper or fiber connections and give them names there or will I need to do this in the post-install section?

Answer (score 1):

Can I use the kickstart to identify copper or fiber connections and give them names there or will I need to do this in the post-install section? From the  [Kickstart commands for network configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user)  you can set from the kickstart

***B.4.1. network (optional)***

Use the optional `network` Kickstart command to configure network information for the target system and activate the network devices in the installation environment. The device specified in the first `network` command is activated automatically. You can also explicitly require a device to be activated using the `--activate` option

`--device=` - specifies the device to be configured (and eventually activated in Anaconda) with the `network` command.

If the `--device=` option is missing on the first use of the `network` command, the value of the `ksdevice=` Anaconda boot option is used, if available. Note that this is considered deprecated behavior; in most cases, you should always specify a `--device=` for every `network` command.

The behavior of any subsequent `network` command in the same Kickstart file is unspecified if its `--device=` option is missing. Make sure you specify this option for any network command beyond the first.

You can specify a device to be activated in any of the following ways:

1. the device name of the interface, for example, `em1`
2. the MAC address of the interface, for example, `01:23:45:67:89:ab`
3. the keyword `link`, which specifies the first interface with its link in the `up` state
4. the keyword `bootif`, which uses the MAC address that pxelinux set in the `BOOTIF` variable. Set `IPAPPEND 2` in your `pxelinux.cfg`  file to have pxelinux set the `BOOTIF` variable.

For example:

> network --bootproto=dhcp --device=em1

***Good Luck Pal***